# CSS target children of a sibling element on hover

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a following situation:

I have 4 cards in a CSS grid. The first one is supposed to be "featured" (different background, etc.) and on hover on the remaining cards, I would like the feature styling change to a hovered card and "unfeature" the first one.

HTML:

```
<div class="benefits__grid">
     <div class="benefits__card">
         <h3>Heading</h3>
         <p>Text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="benefits__card">
         <h3>Heading</h3>
         <p>Text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="benefits__card">
         <h3>Heading</h3>
         <p>Text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="benefits__card">
         <h3>Heading</h3>
         <p>Text</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

I managed to target the featured card by changing the order of elements (so the featured card is last in the DOM but visibly first) and using last-child, as follows:

```
benefits__card:not(:last-child):hover ~ benefits__card(:last-child) {
    background-color: black;
}
```

This works properly. I can't however target the children of the featured card. I would assume something like this should work, but it doesn't:

```
benefits__card:not(:last-child):hover ~ benefits__card(:last-child) h3 {
    color: var(--black);
}
```

Any ideas?

Tried the CSS that is posted in the thread, to no avail.

Comment: Is it possible to add a 'featured' class for the highlighted class?

Comment: That would require JS, wouldn't it? To append and remove classes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a parent hover to cancel the the featured colour:

```css
.benefits__grid:hover .featured {
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
}

.featured,
.benefits__grid .benefits__card:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="benefits__grid">
  <div class="benefits__card featured">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="benefits__card">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="benefits__card">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="benefits__card">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you can't start with the featured class then you could use these selectors

```css
.benefits__grid:hover .benefits__card:first-child {
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
}

.benefits__card:first-child,
.benefits__grid .benefits__card:first-child:hover,
.benefits__grid .benefits__card:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="benefits__grid">
  <div class="benefits__card">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="benefits__card">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="benefits__card">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="benefits__card">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a genius. I was so overcomplicating it, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick below the voting buttons